# What is MinGW lic class?

Tags: mingw

I'm trying to figure why a fresh MinGW install with *base*, *gcc* and *gcc-g++* (and associated dependencies) can't find the  compiler. The setup program has a ***lic class***, but I can't determine what it is, and if its needed for something. Search is producing [spurious noise](http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+mingw+"lic+class")

What, exactly, is a MinGW ***lic class***? Is it needed to make the compiler available?

---

I'm not a MinGW user, so please forgive my ignorance. Rather, some of our users user it, so I have to suffer MinGW problems during testing on occasion (like a missing G++ compiler even though its installed).

Answer (score 1):

It is the license for the package, usually provided as a text document.

It is not needed for compiling, and only needed if you want to read the license terms.